# Is it possible to defeat the Security Demon in Mardek 3?

Tags: mardek-3

Is it possible to defeat the Security Demon in Mardek 3? It seems to me like the Security Demon battle in the warport is rigged by the system such that you can never win.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging from the Fig Hunter wiki page, it does seem to be beatable, but is more of a luck thing than anything else. Here's the page with the strategy:

http://fighunter.wikia.com/wiki/Security_Demon

Comment: +1 for the right answer, and another +1 if I could for informing me that `fighunter.wikia.com` exists.